# Preservation of structure in model theory

Tags: logic, terminology, definition, model-theory

I'm a bit confused about the use of " X preserves Y " in model theory, where X is a placeholder for a map of L-structures of some kind (e.g. homomorphism/ embedding/ isomorphism) and Y is a placeholder for some subset of terms or formulae (e.g. positive formulae/ atomic formulae)
I have seen two distinct usages

- A map $\phi: A \to B$ preserves Y iff $\forall \psi \in Y \forall \bar a \ A \models \phi(\psi(\bar a)) \iff B \models \psi(\phi(\bar a))$ and
- A map $\phi: A \to B$ preserves Y iff $\forall \psi \in Y \forall \bar a \ A \models   \phi(\psi(\bar a)) \implies B \models \psi(\phi(\bar a))$.

Here is an example that I think makes the issue I have clear:

According to Wikipedia, $\phi$ is a homomorphism iff $\phi$ preserves constants and functions ( so far this is clear to me) and $\forall \bar a \forall R\in \operatorname{Pred}(L) \ \bar a \in R^A \implies \phi(\bar a) \in R^B$. In this case would one say $\phi$ preserves relations or not?

The first has an "iff" the latter has "if... then...". Does anyone know what the convention around this terminology is? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking the latter (narrower) version is correct, and the term "reflects" is used for the dual notion. So, for example, surjective homomorphisms preserve but do not necessarily reflect universally-quantified equations, and general homomorphisms preserve but do not necessarily reflect relations.

That said, the conflation of "preserves" and "preserves and reflects" is fairly common (unfortunately, I would argue).

Comment: Thanks! I've read that homomorphism preserve atomic formulae. I assume that relies on the stricter version, as you suggested? This would be incorrect for the first version?

Comment: @user Yes. For example, non-injective homomorphisms are exactly those which do not reflect equality, while every homomorphism (indeed every function) preserves equality.

Comment: I guess I can stop trying to prove the impossible then :)... Thanks alot.